# Rust Workspace: Is it possible to use a binary crate for integrationstests in lib crate?

Tags: testing, rust, dependency-management, rust-cargo

I have the following workspace structure:

```toml
[workspace]

members = [
    "skserver", # binary
    "skclient", # binary
    "skcommon", # lib
    "skintegrationtests" # lib
]
```

The intention was to have an extra lib crate for integration testing of client/server-functionality. The `Cargo.toml` of `skintegrationtests` is as follows:

```toml
# for integration tests of own programs etc.
skcommon = {path = "../skcommon"}
skclient = {path = "../skclient"}
skserver = {path = "../skserver"}
```

`skcommon` can be referenced, but not `skclient` (I haven't tried `skserver`). Is that intentional from Rust? And if so, why?
I started doing integrationtests with `skcommon`. I want to avoid circular dependencies with `skclient` and `skserver`, and so I created `skintegrationtests`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to **run the `skclient` binary** from `skintegrationtests`, then you're looking for [RFC 3028 binary dependencies](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3028-cargo-binary-dependencies.html), which are not yet implemented. There isn't a clean way to do this yet other than a build script separate from Cargo that makes sure the binary is built and then runs the test.

If you want to **call functions defined in the `skclient` package's code**, then you need to modify `skclient` so it is a library package — has a `lib.rs` — and all of the functions wanted are defined there rather than `main.rs`. This does not prevent it from *also* having a binary, which can refer to the library as `use skclient::whatever;`.